# Is it accurate to say that older versions of Jetty cannot be made to work with Java 9 just by configuration changes

Tags: jetty, java-9

Trying to run a fairly old project [Mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute) with Java 9. I was able to get around some initial errors by using

```
--add-modules java.xml.bind
```

but Mamute uses an older version of Jetty (8.1.0.v20120127) and I am seeing

```
PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved
```

This discussion around this [thread](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1498)  would seem to indicate using Jetty with Java 9 is only possible with back-ported code changes and not by changing configuration. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To what [I've experienced](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1758) in recent past, the plan that Jetty community is following is to make Jetty compatible with JDK9 by committing changes to `10.x`(not probably the current `10.0.x` release) and `9.4.x` version(backporting fixes). [***Edit*** - Backported in version [`9.3.x` as well](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1073)]

You can find a list of changes(further redirects) brought in for [JDK9 compatibility](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/487) in jetty. And as one of the comments read that the `9.4.7.RC0` was the first Jetty release built with JDK 9. So seems true to hold that versions prior to these wouldn't entirely support being compatible with JDK9.

Also, you can find a read about [EOL of Jetty 7 and 8](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table) published a good time back, so it makes sense why the changes shouldn't be backported to those versions as well.