# Jetty runtime error only in intelijj IDEA

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty, java-9

I have a maven project. One of its module is war module which I try to start with jetty (jetty:run). 
When I use Netbeans everything is working, but in IntelliJ IDEA I got the strange error.

```
[ERROR] Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@3709748f{/,file:/C:/Users/Gosia/Documents/jaxygen/jaxygen/jaxygen-api-sample/src/main/webapp/;file:/C:/Users/Gosia/Documents/jaxygen/jaxygen/jaxygen-apibrowser-style-simple/src/main/webapp/;jar:file:/C:/Users/Gosia/.m2/repository/org/jaxygen/jaxygen-apibrowser-style-simple/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/jaxygen-apibrowser-style-simple-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.war!/;}
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:149)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1231)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:460)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:124)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.restartWebApp(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo$1.filesChanged(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:402)
    at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportBulkChanges(Scanner.java:486)
    at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:352)
    at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:280)
    at org.mortbay.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:232)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

After this it's look like the server is working, but when start a webpage I got HTTP 503-Service not available.

Can anyone give me a clue why this error is appearing, and why in Netbeans I have no problem to run jetty.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Jetty 6 is a very ancient version. Didn't you try a recent one?

Comment: You might be using different java versions between the IDEs

Comment: The failure was in `parseAnnotations`, can you share some of your annotations that you think might be the issue?

Comment: From what I can tell, Jetty 9 seems to have fixes/changes to work on JDK 9. There are several issues in their issue tracker on this topic.

Comment: Last I remember, I saw a tracker in Jetty project for backporting Java9 compatible changes to Jetty 9.3. I highly doubt that Jetty6 would be compatible as well. I made an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724481/is-it-accurate-to-say-that-older-versions-of-jetty-cannot-be-made-to-work-with-j) sometimes back. Updated today.(thanks for reminding.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem was java 9 and too old jetty. After I update of jetty the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.24/org/mortbay/jetty/plugin/Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java/#119

```
String v = System.getProperty("java.version");
String[] version = v.split("\\.");
if (version==null)
{
    Log.info("Unable to determine jvm version, annotations will not be supported");
    return;
}
int  major = Integer.parseInt(version[0]);
int minor = Integer.parseInt(version[1]);
```

The last line is the line that seems to give you the exception. Also, from your stack trace it can be seen that you use Java 9+ here.

In Java 9, version format has changed: now it's not '1.9' as it would be in the old format, but it's just '9'. Jetty 6 code does not know about this, assumes the old format with a dot and fails (as there is only one element in `version` array instead of expected 2).

Probably, in Netbeans you use JDK 8 or lower, as @Hurda supposed.